# How to remove ionic-tabs from intro page

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Iam trying to remove tabs from intro page and then show them when i navigate to other pages like in the figure below
[image]

my **app.component.ts** looks like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

In my **intro.ts** i have this

```
openPageOne() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page1);
  }
  openPageTwo() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page2);
  }
  openPageThree() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page3);
  }
  openPageFour() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page4);
  }
```

**EDIT**

Below is the code for **tabs.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { IntroPage } from '../intro/intro';
import { Page1} from '../page1/page1';
import { Page2} from '../page2/page2';
import { Page3} from '../page3/page3';
import { Page4} from '../page4/page4';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = Intro;
  tab2Root = Page1;
  tab3Root = Page2;
  tab4Root = Page3;
  tab5Root = Page4;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

I don't know if that edit is able to help

Comment: GO  `app.component.ts` & remove `TabS.page` and put your page `rootPage:any = ExamplePage;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Place your `rootPage` in `app.ts` as `introPage`.
- Then after intro is done `push` to the `tabsPage` where it contains
  all the tabs
- And finally in the `logoutPage` or wherever you want to remove the tabs do the following:

`import {App} from 'ionic-angular'`

`this.app.getRootNav().popToRoot();`

**EDIT**

What i did mean is that you need a seperate `tabsPage` for that contains all the tabs page seperate.

Comment: please check my edit and see if it can give more light

Comment: Please add more light on this: Then after intro is done `push` to the `tabsPage` where it contains all the tabs
And finally in the `logoutPage` or wherever you want to remove the tabs do the following:

Comment: Ok. What i basically meant is that, dont put your `introPage` among with the tabs. Put it in as another page and from that page whenever you click a page goes to the `tabsPage` and from there goes to particular tab number to reach that particular tab. And if you want to go to the `introPage` from the other pages do not include the `introPage` in the tabs which is not a good programming way, but rather try another programming logic that pushes you into the `introPage` from the other pages and then follow my answer.